# LWJGL, Slick Util, 2d rendering sprite without background

Tags: java, background, lwjgl

How to render a sprite without background? I am able to render the whole sprite but I want to ignore the background. I know that it is possible to do, because I saw that kind of rendering in Tibia. Sprites in Tibia are with pink background, which is ignored.
Sprite:

```
public class Sprite {

private Texture texture;


private float sx;
private float sy;
private String extension;
private String path;


/**
 *
 * @param sx
 * @param sy
 * @param extension
 * @param path
 */
public Sprite(float sx, float sy, String extension, String path) {

    this.sx = sx;
    this.sy = sy;
    this.extension = extension;
    this.path = path;
}


public void render() {

    try {
        initTexture();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    Color.white.bind();
    texture.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);


    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, texture.getTextureHeight()*2);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(texture.getTextureWidth()*2, texture.getTextureHeight()*2);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(texture.getTextureWidth()*2, 0);


    glEnd();


}

public float getSx() {
    return sx;
}

public void setSx(float sx) {
    this.sx = sx;
}

public float getSy() {
    return sy;
}

public void setSy(float sy) {
    this.sy = sy;
}

public void initTexture() throws Exception {

    texture = TextureLoader.getTexture(extension, ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying to use a tile-set for your game, which has a purple grid.

I would recommend you to replace the pink color with transparency.
Then, in your program, just do:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The purple TileSets/SpriteSheets were used in older games. There is no actual need for them.